# High CPU system usage caused by ntoskrnl.exe obdereferenceobjectdeferdeletewithtag+0x5c

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Hi so this past July I had done a clean install of Windows 8.1 on an SSD in a ASUS ROG G750JM laptop and ever since then I have noticed random CPU spikes caused by ntoskrnl.exe. I have been trying to solve this issue but no luck. I have made some files and captures of this incident. Any help is appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Jovv_fwSLOUpBnQ36VqoPEf8NQAZ9Ehw?usp=sharing

Comment: Try this: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ntoskrnl-exe-high-cpu-disksage

Comment: I did try these, they didn't work before.